# How to make div 100% height of table cell in IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, html-table

I want to render two dimensional array of equal sized boxes, where the box containing longest content will dictate the height of all boxes, so I decided to use HTML table to line everything up.

However, in IE i'm getting problem where div inside table cell wont fill the whole height, even it works fine in chrome. Here is snippet of the markup and styles:

```
.boxArrayTable td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

<table class="boxArrayTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="box" /></td>
      <td><div class="box" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="box" /></td>
      <td><div class="box" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

div.box {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 222px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Why this doesn't work in IE and how to get it working? Also I should be able to float child elements of box element to bottom.

Comment: your div is not closed within each td

Comment: They are I just forget to close them in sample

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Comment: ^ This explains nothing, why it works with chrome and not in IE, and HOW to make it work in both, when content, thus the height of the table row will be unknown

Answer (score 0):

A step forward is to add

.outer { height: 100vh;}

to The Reveller solution.

Having said that, I cannot get edge to scroll contents where they overflow.

Comment: I think it's min-height that you are thinking of.

Answer (score -1):

You really shouldn't be using tables for layout in this century. If you want to create a table style the simplest option is to set display: table on an outer div and  then display: table-cell on 2 divs inside.

```
div {background-color: yellow;}

.outer {display: table; width: 200px}
.mid {display: table-row;}
.inner {display: table-cell; width: 50%}

<div class="outer">
  <div class="mid">
    <div class="inner">
      Blah
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecusomething blah blah blah you get the idea.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you plan to do this for a living then I would highly recommend learning flexbox layout techbiques.  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ is a good place to start.

Comment: Are you kidding? More than often customers stick with some legacy browser, and you could only dream about modern solutions

Comment: This solution doesn't work. When I specify 100% height for div inside the display: table-cell container, it still doesn't fill the available space in IE, because I haven't specified fixed height to neither outer or mid containers (the content is unknown). Again, in Chrome it works fine. There has to be way to overcome this in IE (Edge)

Comment: Do you want to fill the available space of the browser window? Your question asked for the tallest element to dictate the height, which the above solution does.

Comment: Unless you have a niche (aka corporate) target audience, most users are actually on modern browsers due to auto updating by default. 

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox       http://caniuse.com/usage-table

Comment: But you are using a table layout. That code is functionally and structurally the same as a table. Of course using tables for the entire site is a little old school, but in select places it can be useful for building certain layouts where table functionality can be used if flex is not an option. Using an actual table rather than CSS I think makes it a little clearer. Especially with class names that carry no semantics as to the intent.

Comment: The OP explicitly said that they were using tables in order to fix layout, not for the semantics. Tables are a semantic element and should only be used for that purpose. Most uses of classes aren't semantic and won't affect the reading of the data by assistive tech.